# Preview of custom component in designer

Tags: android, adt

I have custom component that I can place in my layout file (XML) for Android project. Problem is how to change image that is representing it in graphical designer for layout. For now it don't show, because it only extends View class.

As example you could look at code of [Wheel Component](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/), which don't have any graphical representation. It don't need to be exactly representation, just “icon” of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the default drawing (when adapter is null or doesn't have any items) in onDraw method. For example, draw an empty wheel. In my case this was a solution.